# PHP Post input filtering and sanitization

Tags: php, mysql, post, filtering, sanitization

Could some PHP nerd give examples what different ways are good to filter and sanitize PHP form post parameters.

`$somevalue= $_POST['somevalue'];`

My actual thing is that there is many input parameters and those are inserted into mysql database just as they come in. I know it's very bad thing, but I'm not using it in production use YET. So now I'm asking examples to do as title says.

Comment: Welcome to SO.
Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
And [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
And how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

SO is **not a free Coding or Code Conversion or Debugging or Tutorial or Library Finding service**
You also have to show that you have made some effort to solve your own problem.

Comment: If you use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) properly, you don't have to sanitize them.

Comment: "Welcome to SO..." I have made my own research and guess why I'm now here asking this? because internet is a mess.

Answer (score -1):

What comes first to mind is [filter_var](http://php.net/filter_var), then you can check your variable with [is_int](http://php.net/is_int), [is_string](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.is-string.php) and so on.

You also definitely need to escape your variables with [mysqli_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) or any other equivalent functions, depending on what DB you're using.

I hope that better people than myself will complete my answer.

Comment: mysql innodb as on engine.

Comment: No. Do *not* use concatenation and `mysqli_real_escape_string()`. Use prepared statements properly and the library itself will handle escaping data.

Comment: @Phylogenesis, why are you talking about concatenation, I never said anything about it. While I agree with what you say about prepared statement, I forget to mention it, thanks for doing it.

Comment: Why would you combine `mysqli_real_escape_string()` with prepared statements?

Comment: I wouldnt, I never said I would, neither have I talked about concatenation. I am a little bit confused by your question.

Comment: Are you being deliberately obtuse? Your entire second paragraph is about using sanitizing functions such as `mysqli_real_escape_string()`.

Comment: Indeed, the second paragraph is about mysqli_real_escape_string, but since I didn't not talk about prepared statement, I definitely never talked about combining prepared statement with mysqli_real_escape_string.

Comment: The only reason to use that function is if you are using string concatenation to create your queries. My point is that you should not even mention it as an option as it is so inferior to the correct method of sanitization which is to use prepared statements.

Comment: Oh, that's what you meant, sorry, I didn't get that. I agree with you on prepared statement, but since OP didn't say what he was using, I figured that I would be easier for a beginner to use mysqli_*. My mistake.

Comment: I just made tests with prepared statements and it's the best method possible clearly. -> http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

mysqli_real_escape_string() seems to be useless!

Comment: It wasn't at the time we didn't have pdo. ☺